# Does every hypothesis testing require statistical analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

Assuming I am conducting an AB testing on a website to see if there is an increase on user click thru rate. I know there are many different kinds of tests such as t-test, ANOVA, etc. Is it required for me to use these tests if my result is obvious that there is a substantial difference? In other words, when should I use statistical test during my AB testing?

Comment: Welcome, Kay! I think in order to answer your question, we'd need to understand what you mean by "obvious" - while statistical tests are well defined, an "obvious substantial difference" is something that will vary from person to person.

Comment: A hypothesis in a broad scientific sense does not require formal hypothesis testing to prove results one way or another.  Philosophically a hypothesis is a line of inquiry, such as using Newton's laws of gravitation to predict the rate of freefall on the moon. The challenge comes when the observed outcome is stochastic. Consider the "my grandmother ate bacon, drank whiskey, and smoked, and she lived to 90!" anecdotes, but large studies prove that those risk factors lead to poorer survival irrespective of other factors. "Testing" may preclude randomness as spurious inference.

Comment: A more accurate title for this post would be "Does any statistical analysis require hypothesis testing?"

Comment: Sometimes the difference in effect size is so large, both numerically and practically, that a Fisher-Neyman hypothesis test isn't telling you anything you could not have guessed. [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/25b7639fd2b8fd1078c9e2d37e9c7a7f) is a Python gist showing a violin plot where the AB responses are about 10 orders of magnitude different. But much difficulty comes in formally defining when you can and cannot decide to skip hypothesis testing. Domain knowledge is required to know what a practical difference looks like, which isn't accounted for in a t-test or an ANOVA.

Answer (score 1):

This quote answers your question:

> Rejection of a true null hypothesis at the 0.05 level will occur only one in 20 times. The overwhelming majority of these false rejections will be based on test statistics close to the borderline value. If the null hypothesis is false, the inter-ocular traumatic test ["hit between the eyes"] will often suffice to reject it; calculation will serve only to verify clear intuition.

W. Edwards, Harold Lindman, Leonard J. Savage (1962) *Bayesian Statistical Inference for Psychological Research.* University of Michigan. Institute of Science and Technology. (from [here](https://www.rasch.org/rmt/rmt32f.htm))